# node.js with socket.io under debian 5 (lenny) exit with error

Tags: node.js, debian, socket.io, lenny

I installed node.js with the instructions from node.js wiki. So I put the debian sid sources in my sources list and installed node. After that I installed npm with the curl cmd from wiki site. I installed socket.io with npm. Everything till this point works without any errors.

But when I try to start my server I get this error:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^ Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
    at require (module.js:348:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/sockets/trunk/socketio/server.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

I dont have any ideas why this won't work? Could anybody help?

Comment: Where did you install socket.io ? Did you install it in the folder where your server.js file is?

Comment: I installed it with npm, I have no idea where npm stores the intstalled libarys.

Comment: But find says: `find / -name socket.io -type d
/usr/lib/node/.npm/socket.io
/usr/lib/node/.npm/socket.io/0.6.17/package/lib/socket.io
/usr/lib/node/.npm/.cache/socket.io
/usr/lib/node/.npm/.cache/socket.io/0.6.17/package/lib/socket.io
`

Comment: @nesQuick if that's on the server it should have worked. unless permissions etc are not set up properly.

Comment: But it doesn't, thats the reason why i'm here :(

Comment: Try giving an absolute path to socket.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Go to the project folder**. This is the folder where you run node your_server.js.
2. **Run `npm install socket.io`**. This will add a directory under this project folder named node_modules, where, unsurprisingly, modules for this project are.
3. **Run the server** with `node your_server.js`. This time it will work ;).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference socket.io directly in your javascript file.

If you installed socket.io using `npm install socket.io -g` it should have installed socket.io in a node_modules directory under /usr/local/lib. So pick up socket.io from there.

So in your script, reference socket.io like below:

```
var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io');
```

Then run `node /wherever_your_script_is/your_script.js`

Cheers.

P.S. Not sure how npm worked in the past, but today the above would work ok, I just tried it to make sure.